# Python, Django - Find a folder of an installed package

Tags: python, django

In my project, I use Django allauth to allow users to login using their google account. However I want to override the default templates for this package, therefore I need access to the actual **allauth** folder that was created when I did a **pip install**.

I need this folder, as it contains two subfolders I need to add to add to my project. I have already checked a folder called **site_packages** which another answer on a question told me to go check through, however no **allauth** folder was found.

Does anybody know where I can gain access to this folder, so I can use parts of it in my project? Also when I pip installed allauth package, it was not added to my Pipefile, whilst all my other packages were. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A easy way to check the location of a module is to use `__file__`. To find the `allauth` package, try:

```
import allauth
print(allauth.__file__)
```

This should give the full path to `__init__.py` inside of `allauth`. From there you can copy the folder.

Comment: Thank you. Perfect!